# If $(X, d)$ is a complete metric system and $Y \subset X$ is closed, then $(Y, d)$ is a complete metric system

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I begin with an arbitrary Cauchy sequence $\{ a_n \}$ in $Y$. As $Y \subset X$, we have that $\{a_n \} $is a Cauchy sequence in $X$. As $X$ is a complete metric space, $\{a_n \}$ converges to some $a \in X$. At this point, I want to show that $a$ is a limit point of $Y$ by using points from the definition of convergence. For instance, as $\{a_n\} \rightarrow a$, fix $\epsilon >0$ and there is $N_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N_\epsilon$ implies that $d(a_n, a) < \epsilon$. But my question is how can we be sure that our sequence $\{a_n \}$ is not just $a_n = a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$? This sequence is Cauchy, but doesn't grant any distinct points to be able to show that $a$ is a limit point of $Y$ directly. Once I have this, I know that $a \in Y$ as $Y$ is closed, and then $Y$ is complete.

Comment: it's been a while since i last did metric spaces but if $Y \subset X$ is closed, then Y contains all it's limit points. then for any convergent sequence (which would all be cauchy) they would converge to a point in Y, and if the sequence is cauchy but divergent then wouldn't it be unbounded?...or at the very least containing subsequences to two or more seperate limit points, in which case are they cauchy?

again it's been a while which is why im not putting this up as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n = a$ for all $n$ (or just one), then $a\in Y$ as $a_n\in Y$ for all $n$ by assumption.

Answer (score 0):

the old way i remember doing this is this:

let X be complete, with $Y \subset_{closed} X$, let $x_n$ be a cauchy sequence in Y, since X is complete $x_n \longrightarrow x$ for some $x \in X$, since Y is closed, $x \in Y$

so long as x is a limit point for some convergent sequence in Y, and Y is closed x must be contained in Y, no matter what form it takes.